How to quantify arable land output potential?
How do economists assess the production potential of arable land? More specifically, how is land fertility quantified?
For example, how would I compare countries by their agricultural potential by capita leaving aside factors such as access to markets, level of mechanization etc.  Just the potential to produce given equal inputs.
